# Is there a way to use PIVOT syntax to accomplish the following?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have table_A and want to have a result like table_B.  I can accomplish this by using a WHILE loop with a counter a loop 12 times to get my data in the format I want in table_B.  Wondering if there was a cleaner way.  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

--Unpivot the table.

```
SELECT Location, Account,Dept, Year, Month, Amount 
FROM 
   (SELECT Location, Account,Dept, Year, Month, Amount, January ... Dec
   FROM Table_A) p
UNPIVOT
   (Amount FOR Month IN 
      (January, Feb ... Dec)
)AS Table_B;
GO
```

reference: [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

@DecoderReloaded showed how this is typically accomplished using the built-in `UNPIVOT` method.

This answer shows an alternate method of using `CROSS APPLY` to extend the functionality that is possible by using `UNPIVOT`.

Create a table:

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableA') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TableA;
CREATE TABLE #TableA
(
    [Location] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    , Account VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    , Dept CHAR(2) NOT NULL
    , [Year] INT NOT NULL
    , January DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , February DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , March DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , April DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , May DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , June DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , July DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , August DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , September DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , October DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , November DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , December DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
);
```

Insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO #TableA(Location, Account, Dept, Year, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)
VALUES ('Store1', '5151', '10', 2015, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220)
    , ('Store2', '5151', '10', 2015, 111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 201, 211, 221)
    , ('Store3', '5150', '11', 2015, 112, 122, 132, 142, 152, 162, 172, 182, 192, 202, 212, 222);
```

"Unpivot" the data using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT a.Location
    , a.Account
    , a.Dept
    , a.Year
    , up.MonthCol
    , up.MonthVal
    , YearlyTotalByLocAcctDept = SUM(up.MonthVal) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Location, a.Account, a.Dept, a.Year)
    , PercentOfTotalByLocAcctDept = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), up.MonthVal) / SUM(up.MonthVal) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Location, a.Account, a.Dept, a.Year) * 100)
    , YearlyTotal = SUM(up.MonthVal) OVER ()
    , PercentOfTotal = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), up.MonthVal) / SUM(up.MonthVal) OVER () * 100)
FROM #TableA a
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES ('January', a.January, 1)
        , (' February', a.February, 2)
        , (' March', a.March, 3)
        , (' April', a.April, 4)
        , (' May', a.May, 5)
        , (' June', a.July, 6)
        , (' July', a.July, 7)
        , (' August', a.August, 8)
        , (' September', a.September, 9)
        , (' October', a.October, 10)
        , (' November', a.November, 11)
        , (' December', a.December, 12)
        ) up(MonthCol, MonthVal, MonthNum)
ORDER BY a.Location
    , a.Account
    , a.Dept
    , a.Year
    , up.MonthNum;
```

The output from the `SELECT` query:

[image]

As you can see from the output, the single row input data is pivoted into multiple rows, one for each month.  I've also added 4 columns to the query that provide further analysis of the data.  These 4 extra columns are not easily generated when using the standard `UNPIVOT` operator.

I wrote a blog post about the use of [CROSS APPLY](http://www.sqlserver.science/t-sql/cross-apply-as-an-alternative-to-unpivot/).